# Can I do vim-like completions in emacs?

Tags: completion

For example, I can open a bare vim (without plugin) and input `some_long_object` and then hit `Enter` to open a new line, and input a `s`, hit `C-x C-p`, it will complete `some_long_object` for me. If I input `some_long_object.some_method_really_long` on a new line, then I open a new line and input `s`, then hit `C-x C-p C-x C-p`, it will complete `some_long_object.some_method_really_long` for me.

Vim can also do the same kind of thing on lines.(not only complete word, but also lines)

Out-of-box Emacs seems not doing word completion, line completion, and series completion as good as Vim. It only has an expand. when I use Vim, I can `C-x C-p` to complete a word, (maybe it is a `some_object`)and sequentially hit another `C-x C-p` to complete it, hoping to check what should be following a `some_object`, (for example it is a `some_object.some_method`), and `C-x C-l` will complete line or (use in sequence) lines for me.

So vim can complete one thing after another and I need not think about what should appear next if I am sure what should appear when I hit `C-x C-p`.

And another thing, I can use `C-x C-p` to recall what method I've used in this buffer but do not have to really finish the completion.

I heard of but have not used `evil` before. Can evil do the same thing as I just said? and can I use `evil` just for completion, not using its other kdbs? I've used to Emacs key bindings and have not used vim for at least 5 years.

---

I'm been using `hippie-expand` for years. I don't like the way it does things because it does not give me any feedback how I can use it. It's like exploring on a website without UE designing. I even tried `hippie-expand` with `ido` menu. It's just not what I need. I'm not familiar with `auto-complete` because when I tried it a few years ago, it was full of problems, and besides that its user experience was not as good as vim's completion. Vim's completion just provides me everything what I need and not any more or or any less.

So is there any Emacs extensions, or tweeks that can help me to do completion just like the way as I said?

---

I've been using Emacs for years. Emacs provides me many huge good things, but with this simple completion thing, I've tried again and again. Maybe the user experience philosophy behind Emacs is not so good as Vim.
For example, `auto-complete` claims it has built a LOW COST operation philosophy behind it. But for me, the simple thing is it uses a input-userlookup-feedback-input-userlookup-feedback loop in its philosophy. It is slower than vim, because vim use a input->not_good?->simple_adjust philosophy. Behind vim it is real Unix philosophy, which is splitting complex things to simple parts. Try to lower the feedback cost and decrease feedback-loop is the central thing what vim provide us.

Comment: What does "just like in vim" mean ?

Comment: I do not know much about vi. I just know that `evil` is a vi-layer for emacs: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil Maybe, you can try that one.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. Sorry for not expressing myself clearly. I mean i want Emacs to do word completion, line completion, and completion one after another. when I use vim, I can C-x C-p to complete a word, (maybe it is a 'some_object')and do another C-x C-p to complete it by checking what should be following a 'some_object', (for example it is a 'some_object.some_method'), and C-x C-l do exactly the same thing.

Comment: It can complete one line after another and I need not think about what should appear next if I am sure what should appear when I hit C-x C-p. I have not used `evil` before. Can `evil` do the same thing as I just said? and can I use `evil` just for completion? I've used to Emacs and have not used vim for at least 5 years.

Comment: vi/ViM doesn’t do completion on its own. What plugin do you use for that? What packages have you tried with Emacs already?

Comment: no plugin. I can open a bare vim and input a `asdf` hit `Enter`, and input a `a`, hit `C-x C-p` it will complete `asdf` for me. if i input a `asdf.bbb`, then i input `a` in a new line, and hit `C-x C-p C-x C-p`, it will complete `asdf.bbb` for me.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant stuff from your comments. Comments can be deleted at any time. The question should stand alone and be clear.

Comment: It may be surprising, but Emacs ain't Vim.  If the existing options are not satisfying to you, it's time to hack together something yourself.  That is the Emacs philosophy.

Comment: @wasamasa ok thanks. Maybe it is time when i should start learning lisp

Comment: I couldn't follow your description of completion in Vim and so didn't understand what you wanted. So I ran Vim and tried it. Is what you want that repeated uses of completion add the stuff that comes in the buffer after the first thing completed? There is also a pink popup with completion options. Do you want something like that too?

Comment: If what you are after is that successive completions copy more and more text from where the first bit was found, you can do something that like with `dabbrev-expand` (normally bound to `M-/`): if after expanding you press `<space>` and then `M-/` again, it copies the next bit of text after the completion.

Comment: Yes, I love all things about completion in vim. And yes, I've been using `dabbrev-expand` till now. one thing is it has no controls on what I want to complete(maybe this time I want to complete a word, next time I want to complete a line. i could only cycle from them), second thing is no pop up window shows, third thing is it needs another `<space>` or movement to do another completion and I cannot do series completions. Say I have a long sequence of method calls in functional programming, it need double amount of operations than vim.

Comment: Try the solution in this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/7fx7qj/keeping_company_with_hippies_another_look_at/). It combines hippie-expand and company to give you a popup menu of lines from the current buffer. I think it'll give you what you want for line completion, at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GNU Emacs has a way to complete words based on buffers you have open. It's bound to <kbd>M-/</kbd> by default.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dynamic-Abbrevs.html

Comment: Thanks. What I really need is to change the way Emacs do completion, it's user exprience, the feedback it provides when doing completion, not what word/line Emacs can complete.

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look at `evil-maps.el`, you'll see that it defines a few of Vim's completion commands:

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map "\C-n" 'evil-complete-next)
(define-key evil-insert-state-map "\C-p" 'evil-complete-previous)
(define-key evil-insert-state-map "\C-x\C-n" 'evil-complete-next-line)
(define-key evil-insert-state-map "\C-x\C-p" 'evil-complete-previous-line)
```

The definition of `C-x C-p` is:

```
(evil-define-command evil-complete-previous-line (&optional arg)
  "Complete a whole line.
Calls `evil-complete-previous-line-func'."
  :repeat change
  (interactive "P")
  (if (minibufferp)
      (funcall evil-complete-previous-minibuffer-func)
    (funcall evil-complete-previous-line-func arg)))
```

Where `evil-complete-previous-line-func` happens to be:

```
#'(lambda (arg)
    (let ((hippie-expand-try-functions-list
           '(try-expand-line
             try-expand-line-all-buffers)))
      (hippie-expand arg)))
```

From this I can judge that what you're after is [hippie-expand](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand) with the above customization to `hippie-expand-try-functions-list`.  It is a more versatile tool than dabbrev if you're willing to invest a bit of time into it.

Comment: Thanks, `hippie-expand` is like walking on bare feet, even with `ido` menu, whereas Emacs' `auto-complete` like sitting in an broken cart, and Vim's simple completion implementation is just like flying in a plane.

Comment: Feel free to write an auto-complete-mode or company backend to hippie-expand. Poetry won't get you anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/redguardtoo/eacl - Emacs auto complete line(s)

The difference between eacl and other solutions:

- it gets more candidate by grepping files (using GNU Grep) in current project (project root is automatically detected if you use git/svn/mercurial)
- it can complete multi line statement by grepping (a statement ends with ",". Its definition can be customized by `eacl-statement-regex`)